# How to restore a SQL Server 2012 database .bak file in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, authentication

I have developed a MIS in Windows Forms in which I took backup of my SQL Server 2012 database, but I am unable to restore the backup (`.bak`) file.

This is my code:

```
private void buttonRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Backup File |*.bak";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string sql = "Alter Database BOQ SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;";
            sql += "Restore Database BOQ FROM DISK ='" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "' WITH REPLACE;";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=BOQ;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,con);

            con.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Database Recovered Successfully!");
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You **cannot** connect to your database `BOQ` and then restore a `.bak` over top of it!

```
"Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=BOQ;Integrated Security=True"
                                ****
```

You need to connect to the `master` database, and **then** you can restore your `BOQ` database:

```
"Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"
                                *******
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I cannot figure out how one would first connect to the master database and then to the one which is to be restored? Some clarification would be great.  Thanks

Comment: @PeterJ: just use the *second* connection string I showed in my answer to connect to `master`, and when you're done restoring the database, close that connection and use the *first* connection string to connect to the actual database you want to use (and which you've just restored)

Comment: Oh, ok, that makes sense.  Thanks a million, marc_s!