# How to restore databse SQL 2008 in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore

I want to restore database in C#, use file type .BAK

```
var db = new QLTDEntities();
var con = ((SqlConnection)db.Database.Connection);
con.Open();
string stringquery = "RESTORE DATABASE TEST FROM DISK ='D:\ABC.BAK'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stringquery, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I get error at line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

```
'TEST' is not a recognized RESTORE option.
```

Can you tell me what i mistake or wrong place.?

Comment: I don't see _any_ `TEST` option in `RESTORE` syntax. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx. Is it database name?

Comment: This is not a C# problem, this is an SQL problem, you don't know the correct SQL to restore a database with. When you do, the C# code you have is going to work.

Comment: Dear Soner, oh I want to restore full database, what I need the option in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
string stringquery = @"USE master BACKUP DATABASE [TEST] TO DISK='D:\ABC.BAK'";
```

Comment: Oh, you right."RESTORE" like this.It's work,thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the master database, and then you can restore your database.

Have a look at
[How to restore a SQL Server 2012 database .bak file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576614/how-to-restore-a-sql-server-2012-database-bak-file-in-c)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26390/SQL-Server-2005-Database-Backup-and-Restore-using

Comment: I use SQL Server 2008